# Just started working with jwplayer, I have a few questions

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, jwplayer

I just started working with jwplayer and I have a few questions:

1. How do I attach/show a thumbnail next to the title(similar to youtube)? Do I have to create the thumbnails myself or does jwplayer does this for me?
2. The playlist section looks dull, it just shows the title. How can I show some additional information for the video? ie time, author/uploader etc.

Please point me to documentation if there is one, so far I've not found it.

My current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        playlist: [{
            file: "/common/assets/sample_iPod.m4v",
            title: "Sample Video 1"
        },{
            file: "/common/assets/Wildlife_512kb.mp4",
            title: "Animals being CUTE!!!"
        },{
            file: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/asteroid.static.www.otcmarkets.com/videos_presentations/OTCM/Wildlife_512kb.mp4",
            title: "video from S3"
        },{
            file: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/asteroid.static.www.otcmarkets.com/videos_presentations/OTCM/sample_iPod.m4v",
            title: "ipod help from S3"
        }],
        width: 770,
        height: 360,
        listbar: {
            position: 'right',
            size: 240
        }
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do these, you would add an image, as well as a description, to each playlist entry.

Reference - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29249/playlist-sidebar-component

Code used:

```
<div id="myElement"></div>

<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
      playlist: [{
        file: "/uploads/sintel.mp4",
        image: "/uploads/sintel.jpg",
        title: "Sintel Trailer",
        description: "Sintel is a fantasy CGI movie from the Blender Open Movie Project."
      },{
        file: "/uploads/tears.mp4",
        image: "/uploads/tears.jpg",
        title: "Tears of Steel Trailer",
        description: "A complete open pipeline was used to produce this visual effect film."
      },{
        file: "/uploads/bunny.mp4",
        image: "/uploads/bunny.jpg",
        title: "Big Buck Bunny Trailer",
        description: "This  animated film is made using free and open source software."
      },{
        file: "/uploads/elephants.mp4",
        image: "/uploads/elephants.jpg",
        title: "Elephants Dream Trailer",
        description: "This is the worlds first open movie, made entirely with Blender."
      }],
      width: 700,
      height: 240,
      listbar: {
        position: "right",
        size: 280
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hmmmm, so there is no way i can show the uploaded date for this then?

Comment: Not unless you just put the dates into the description, for example.

Comment: i see, few more questions, ive upload a screenshot, notice on the right side of the playlist, the description is almost touching the edge, anyway i can move the description to the left a bit so the description isnt so close to the edge? lastly, since i dont plan on making the thumbnails myself, is it possible to have the playlist without the big X(box) next to title/description such that the playlist only shows the title/description/etc?

Comment: 1) Can I see where this is running? 2) This is only possible by making a custom skin and removing the image from the playlist from the skin's xml file. We have a SDK available here - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/

Comment: this is currently on my dev box. i've tried changing the size of the player around but couldnt fix that. i will look over the sdk then. thanks!!

Comment: Np! It is weird, this example doesn't have that issue - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29249/playlist-sidebar-component

Comment: im gonna go ahead and guess that it is probably because mine didnt have the scroll bar. thanks for the help man! appreciate it!!